# ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes is always null when requesting scopes other than API resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

Why is `ProfileDataRequestContext.RequestedClaimTypes` null, when the request's key-value pair `scopes` has no **API** resources (but other things like identity resources - openid, profile, phone etc.)

Why are they not counted as "Requested"? How would one then know what claims to include in the JWT that's about to be generated?

Obviously if I request an **API** resource and all my claims are listed under the property of `UserClaims`, everything works as expected. (The listed claims in there, are added to the `requestedClaimTypes` collection.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ProfileService is called on token creation, but with different contexts:

- `Context.Caller = ClaimsProviderAccessToken`
- `Context.Caller = UserInfoEndpoint`

So it depends on the type of generated token.

For the *access token* only resource scopes are allowed (ApiResources) and for the *identity token* that is returned only identity scopes are allowed (IdentityResources).

Though by default the id_token will only contain the `sub` claim. Additional information can be requested at the UserInfo endpoint.

Comment: That must explain it. I was testing out ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentials flow, and I believe in that flow no identity token is ever issued, correct? Hence why the access token will only add claims, if any Api Resources are requested in the `scopes` key-value pair. If you later use that access token to request identity scopes from the UserInfo endpoint, will it fail?

Comment: could you please confirm?

Comment: @SpiritBob ROPC is oauth2, not oidc. So there is no id_token in that flow. For other flows, it depends on what the client requests. If the client requests the 'profile' scope or has the option GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint enabled then the endpoint will be hit at some point, or is otherwise accessable by the client. I'm not sure if the endpoint is also called for the id_token that is part of the login result, since that token will only contain the sub claim.

Comment: Profile is a scope, one that may require consent from the user. So yes, the client has to request the scope. If the id_token is requested as part of the flow, then it will only contain the sub claim. But in that case the client can use the access token to request the full id_token from the UserInfo endpoint. The endpoint itself will not fail (as in BadRequest) when the profile scope is not requested by the client or the user didn't give consent, the profile claims will simply not be included in the token.

Comment: As a sidenote, do not use ROPC. It's no longer part of the documentation for a reason. Please read [this article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) for a good explanation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of ROPC being a very bad candidate for anything, except in very rare cases. I just used it for testing purposes.

I'm not sure why you claim that only the "sub" claim is contained in the id_token, when identityServer4 seems to put a lot of more information in it?

Comment: @SpiritBob That's explained [here](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/14/optimizing-identity-tokens-for-size/). By default when the `id_token` is requested along with the `access_token`, it is optimized to only contain the `sub` claim, unless client settings override this behaviour. When calling the UserInfo endpoint, then all allowed claims are included.

Comment: Thank you for that read, I noticed that I had this enabled - `GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint`. This basically hits the `UserInfoEndpoint` after the `id_token` is returned as you said, but even if this is set to `false`, the `id_token` still contains a lot more information. Why?
                                                
Link to mockup identity token returned: https://pastebin.com/raw/PJT1rq0i

Comment: @SpiritBob Yes, claims that are part of the signature and required in order to validate the token. But it does not contain "user" claims other than `sub`. Despite being optimized, the token remains quite large, as also mentioned in the comments section of the linked article.